# Cannot Resolve Symbol CrimeFragment Android Studio

Tags: android

I am getting a cannot resolve symbol error on CrimeFragment and I don't know why.  I am a beginner so I'm not sure how to fix this.  Here is the code for CrimeActivity.java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class CrimeActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you aren't importing your class CrimeFragment

Comment: I know this may seem like a stupid question but I am a very novice programmer.  How do I do that?

Comment: you click on the CrimeFragment word, then alt+enter to auto import (on mac)

Comment: There is no auto import option with alt + enter.  I do also have a CrimeFragment java class.  Could the error involve that somehow?

Comment: https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf

Comment: How is that supposed to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that CrimeFragment.java and Crime.java are in the right packages. Select "Packages" view in the top-left corner. If these files hang around separately at the bottom, drag and drop them into the "com.(..).criminalintent" package.